# Selling BTC from BitMinter

Tags: exchanges, address, sell-bitcoins, trade

I have started mining with [BitMinter.com](http://bitminter.com) and am nearing a complete bitcoin. I have searched for hours for my account/wallet address so I can move bitcoins from BitMinter to an exchange. I can't seem to find that, or any way to sell any bitcoins I have worked for. How do I get my bitcoin from BitMinter to somewhere like [fastcash4bitcoins.com](http://fastcash4bitcoins.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitminter has an auto cash out function. On the [Account homepage](https://bitminter.com/members/), you can set a Bitcoin address to which your coins are deposited as soon as you reach a certain amount.

I assume you already have a Bitcoin wallet somewhere that can give you an address to enter in the auto cash out form. If you don't, visit [this page](http://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) on the Bitcoin website and create a wallet. (I recommend you for simplicity and security considerations to choose a web wallet or a fast wallet like Multibit or Electrum.)

Once you set up auto cash out, you will receive your bitcoins in your wallet. They you can create an account on [an exchange that allows you to sell bitcoins](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins). They will give you a deposit address to which you will need to send your bitcoins using your wallet. As soon as the deposit arrives, you can sell your coins and withdraw the cash from the exchange site.

Comment: Ah I see, I was under the assumption that the bitminter.com account was my wallet. Thank you very much for your explanation!